# In MVC, model.isvalid is checked client side or server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think it is checkeon server side, but it gives of feeling of being checked on client side.

```
public ActionResult(Model myModel){
 if (ModelState.IsValid){
       ----------
  }
}
```

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` is server side code (a browser has no knowledge of c# code)

Comment: but we can also check the validity of model in view itself using : @ViewData.ModelState.IsValid

Comment: That is still server side code (its executed on the server before the view is sent to the browser)

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` certainly validates input on server-side. Even present in a view, it still requires server code rendering first. It depends on how `RequiredAttribute` & other attribute values were fulfilled before sending request.

Comment: what are other way of checking validity except of jquery validation and ModelState

Comment: You can write what ever code you want to validate your model. But why would you when the framework already provides that mechanism via `ValidationAttributes` and `ModelState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelState.IsValid` is server side code and Browser has no idea about what it is! You can use **`Jquery Validation`** at client side !!

Comment: what are other way of checking validity except of jquery validation and ModelState

Comment: @Rajdeep , it is depends on the requirement but mostly at client side `Jquery Validations` are more preferable

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid always checked at server side whether your model contains any error or not.